# Hindu equivalent of Cain and Abel? A story of jealousy, vengeance and punishment

Tags: puranas, story

In the old testament, there is the story of [Cain and Abel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain_and_Abel)

> In the biblical Book of Genesis, Cain and Abel are the first two sons
> of Adam and Eve. Cain, the firstborn, was a farmer, and his brother
> Abel was a shepherd. The brothers made sacrifices to God, each of his
> own produce, but God favored Abel's sacrifice instead of Cain's. Cain
> then murdered Abel, whereupon God punished Cain by condemning him to a
> life of wandering.

This is a story of Jealousy, Vengeance and Punishment.

---

Is there any story in Hinduism which is morally equivalent to this? One immediate comparison is that of war between Kauravas and Pandavas. But there the good side wins. So the story's climax is totally different.

Any story from Upanishads, Puranas, Upa Puranas, Upakathas of Mahabharata and Ramyana would do.

Comment: Mahabharata is not just one story. It contains several stories. There are lots of examples of vengeance, jealousy and punishment in Mahabharata, Puranas as well as Ramayana. Just take the example of Karna, a warrior prince in Mahabharata. His life is mixed with such stories.

Comment: @vidyarthi I should have been clear, when I said Mahabharata I meant the war between cousin brothers, of Pandavas and Kauravas.